how to get country and state by phone number in android studio
I am creating a communication app so how can i get country and state by phone number. I am creating a communication app so how can i get country and state by phone number in android studo . if you are you know the answer please help me.

You don't mention which countries you are targeting.  But for most countries, there are more mobile phone numbers than private fixed lines, and mobile phone numbers are location independent.  So getting a state won't work most of the time.

You can't.  You can get country-ish.  A phone number has a country code in it, but multiple countries can share a code.  USA and Canada share the code "1".  A partial list can be found https://countrycode.org/
Within the US an area code tends to be within 1 state, but with the adoption of mobile phones and phone number portability they no longer mean anything.  My area code is for Washington state.  I haven't lived in WA since 2012.  So an area code can be used to guess a state, but it's likely to be right about 60% of the time.  Not to mention various area codes that don't belong to a geographical area like an 800 number.
